# Elasticsearch - How to create buckets by using information from two fields at the same time?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

My documents are like this:

```py
{'start': 0, 'stop': 3, 'val': 3}
{'start': 2, 'stop': 4, 'val': 1}
{'start': 5, 'stop': 6, 'val': 4}
```

We can imagine that each document occupies the x-coordinates from `'start'` to `'stop'`,
and has a certain value `'val'` (`'start' < 'stop'` is guaranteed).

**The goal** is to plot a line showing the sum of these values `'val'` from all the
documents which occupy an x-coordinate:

[image]

<sup>[this graph online](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/c7wmbun3ib)</sup>

In reality there are many documents with many different `'start'` and `'stop'` coordinates. Speed is important, so:

#### Is this possible to do with at most a couple of elastic search requests? how?

---

**What I've tried:**

With one elastic search request we can get the `min_start`, and `max_stop` coordinates. These will be the boundaries of x.

Then we divide the x-coordinates into `N` intervals, and in a loop for each interval we make an elastic search request: to filter out all the documents which lie completely outside of this interval, and do a sum aggregation of `'val'`.

This approach takes too much time because there are `N+1` requests, and if we want to have a line with higher precision, the time will increase linearly.

Code:

```py
N = 300  # number of intervals along x

x = []
y = []

data = es.search(index='index_name',
                 body={
                    'aggs': {
                        'min_start': {'min': {'field': 'start'}},
                        'max_stop': {'max': {'field': 'stop'}}
                    }
                 })
min_x = data['aggregations']['min_start']['value']
max_x = data['aggregations']['max_stop']['value']

x_from = min_x
x_step = (max_x - min_x) / N
for _ in range(N):
    x_to = x_from + x_step
    
    data = es.search(
        index='index_name', 
        body= {
            'size': 0,  # to not return any actual documents

            'query': {
                'bool': {
                    'should': [
                        # start is in the current x-interval:
                        {'bool': {'must': [
                            {'range': {'start': {'gte': x_from}}},
                            {'range': {'start': {'lte': x_to}}}
                        ]}},

                        # stop is in the current x-interval:
                        {'bool': {'must': [
                            {'range': {'stop': {'gte': x_from}}},
                            {'range': {'stop': {'lte': x_to}}}
                        ]}},

                        # current x-interval is inside start--stop
                        {'bool': {'must': [
                            {'range': {'start': {'lte': x_from}}},
                            {'range': {'stop': {'gte': x_to}}}
                        ]}}
                    ],
                    'minimum_should_match': 1  # at least 1 of these 3 conditions should match
                }
            },

            'aggs': {
                'vals_sum': {'sum': {'field': 'val'}}
            }
        }
    )
    
    # Append info to the lists:
    x.append(x_from)    
    y.append(data['aggregations']['vals_sum']['value'])
    
    # Next x-interval:
    x_from = x_to


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this in one single query is to use the [`range` field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html) ([available since 5.2](https://www.elastic.co/blog/numeric-and-date-ranges-in-elasticsearch-just-another-brick-in-the-wall)) instead of using two fields `start` and `stop` and reimplementing the same logic. Like this:

```
PUT test 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "range": {
        "type": "integer_range"
      },
      "val": {
        "type":"integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your documents would look like this:

```
    {
      "range" : {
        "gte" : 0,
        "lt" : 3
      },
      "val" : 3
    }
```

And then the query would simply leverage an `histogram` aggregation like this:

```
POST test/_search 
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "histo": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "range",
        "interval": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "val"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the results are as expected: 3, 3, 4, 1, 0, 4